Using addresses from subnet v6 vultr
Hi I have an inquiry for you guys, is it possible to use the address from the subnet//64 ipv6 through applications without bind it?
I currently have an address, and I would like a python script to be able to use the address from this pool to execute requests
inet6 2001:19f0:5c01:171c:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx/64 scope global dynamic noprefixroute
I have a code snippet created but am thinking if there is a workaround to not use bindings
def generate_ipv6_address(prefix):
    network = ipaddress.IPv6Network(prefix)
    address = network.network_address + random.randint(1, network.num_addresses - 2)
    return str(address)

def configure_ipv6_address(interface, address):
    try:
        result = subprocess.run(['sudo', 'ip', 'addr', 'add', f"{address}/128", 'dev', interface], check=True, capture_output=True, text=True)
        print(f"Configured address {address} on interface {interface}")
        return True
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        print(f"Failed to add address {address} to interface {interface}: {e}")
        return False

def remove_ipv6_address(interface, address):
    try:
        result = subprocess.run(['sudo', 'ip', 'addr', 'del', f"{address}/128", 'dev', interface], check=True, capture_output=True, text=True)
        print(f"Removed address {address} from interface {interface}")
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        print(f"Failed to remove address {address} from interface {interface}: {e}")

def check_ipv6_address(interface, address):
    try:
        result = subprocess.run(['ip', '-6', 'addr', 'show', 'dev', interface], capture_output=True, text=True)
        output = result.stdout
        for line in output.splitlines():
            if address in line and "tentative" not in line:
                return True
        return False
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        print(f"Failed to check address {address} on interface {interface}: {e}")
        return False


Does this answer your question? Can I bind a (large) block of addresses to an interface?
